# Find All Window title in selected process

Tags: vb.net

I would like query how much Window is opened in selected process.

For example i have downloaded example.exe
example.exe is opening 2 window:
Form1
Form2

How i find the all window title in VB.net (Visual Basic)?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and where exactly your problem is. See here for how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Nice but your code listing only the main form. Form2 title is not listed.

Answer (score 0):

this is your code

```
    Dim processlist As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()
    Dim myProcess As String = "myProcessName"


    For Each proc As Process In processlist

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle) And proc.ProcessName = myProcess Then

            MessageBox.Show("Process name : " & proc.ProcessName.ToString() & " Title name : " & proc.MainWindowTitle.ToString())

        End If

    Next
```